# How do I list item price in woocommerce checkout and confirmation e-mails?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce displays individual item price in checkout, but not in order confirmations.

I don't need it to display a new column.  Something simple like `($x.xx each)` after the item name.

All of my pricing is based off variations, so I modified the code below to display variation descriptions, then I manually enter the "$x.xx each" as the description.  It should be pretty easy to modify this to display price instead, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I just need to know how to change `$_var_description` to show price instead of description.  Thanks!

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_title_as_link', 10, 2);
function display_product_title_as_link($item_name, $item)
{

    $_product = get_product($item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id']);

    $link = get_permalink($_product->id);

    $_var_description = '';

    if ($item['variation_id']) {
        $_var_description = $_product->get_variation_description();

    }
    if ($_var_description) {
        return '' . $item_name . ' (' . $_var_description . ')';
    } else {
        return '' . $item_name;
    }
}
```

Expected results is on order confirmations it will say Item name + individual price instead of item name.

Answer (score 1):

Add the follows code snippet to do the above -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_price_in_item_title', 10, 2 );
function add_price_in_item_title( $item_name, $item ) {
    $order = $item->get_order();
    $item_price = wc_price( $item->get_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
    if( $item->get_total() ) {
        return $item_name . ' (' . $item_price . ')';
    } else {
        return $item_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It's close to what I want.  However, you're getting the TOTAL, where as I want the INDIVIDUAL item price.  How can I call the individual price?

Comment: Use $item->get_subtotal() for individual item price.

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_price_in_item_title', 10, 2 );
function add_price_in_item_title( $item_name, $item ) {
    $order = $item->get_order();
    $item_price = wc_price( ($item->get_total()/ $item->get_quantity()), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
    if( ($item->get_total()/ $item->get_quantity()) ) {
        return $item_name . ' (' . $item_price . ')';
    } else {
        return $item_name;
    }
}
```

I change a bit itzmekhokan code and use this on my web, and it's work show single price on checkout page